# pyodbc: can't execute very long sql statement

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to execute a very long statement from python which has around 1.3 million characters using following code:

```
import pyodbc

conn_str = 'Driver={SQL Server}; 
SERVER=MYSERVER;DATABASE=MyDatabase;TrustedConnection=True'
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = conn.cursor()

try:
    cursor.execute("A SQL statement with 1.3m characters")
    cursor.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    conn.close()
```

It's basically a long list of insert statements.
I am watching the SQL Profiler as this is running against my SQL server and it executes every time a different number of INSERT statements. It inserts the data up to around 40k characters. Then it suddenly stops. I was thinking of a max number of characters that a sql statement can hold, but since it's executing a different number of statements that doesn't sound like the issue here?

Any one any ideas what's happening here and how I could get around this?

Thanks,
Joe

Edit:
here is the query:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

IF (select  max(id)
    from    Table1) = 87648
BEGIN

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (87649, 'G4KG72HF6','87649');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (87650, 'G4KG72HF6','87650');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (87651, 'GDGVFKVW6','87651');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (87652, 'GYAPWLNU1','87652');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (87653, 'GYAPWLNU1','87653');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (87654, 'H884542A2','87654');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (87655, 'HT2XM4U83','87655');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (87656, 'GPD9P39C7','87656');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (87657, 'J2ZBUN7Q7','87657');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (87658, 'JBWS35M69','87658');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (87659, 'JMU6ANZN7','87659');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (87660, 'JWRLK6D48','87660');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (87661, 'K6NZSPSL2','87661');


--- a lot more inserts happening here



    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT N'ERROR: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
        ROLLBACK
        PRINT N'Transaction rolled back' 
END
END CATCH

END

ELSE
PRINT 'Max id in Table1 != 87648, has this script been ran already?'
```

Comment: There are many ways to bulk import or load data into databases. Plus, consider creating a stored procedure of these append queries and call it from Python. How did you get a query of 1.5 million characters? If from csv/txt/XML/Excel data, use aforementioned bulk operations.

Comment: I am trying to keep it quite generic, so no matter what string is passed in this code shouldn't mind. When I execute this from SSMS there are no issues at all. Finishes within seconds. Any idea why this wouldn't work?

Comment: Without actual SQL code, I cannot help. Possibly you are having timeout issues with long processing. And if all work with SSMS, again build a stored procedure of those commands and have pyodbc call it: `EXEC mystoreproc`.

Comment: Does your (absurdly long) SQL statement begin with `SET NOCOUNT ON;`? If not, then each INSERT statement may be generating an update count that gets queued so it can be returned to your Python app, and there may be a limit as to how long that queue can be.

Comment: Re: edit - Prepend `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to your string and see if that helps.

Comment: That worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> It's basically a long list of insert statements

Since your SQL text does not begin with `SET NOCOUNT ON;`, each INSERT statement is generating an update count that gets queued so it can be returned to your Python app, and there is a limit as to how long that queue can be.

So, just prepend `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to your SQL text to avoid the problem.

(See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/277) for a more thorough discussion.)